# assign value to variable on variable declaration? BC AL

Tags: nav, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al, businesscentral

Is it possible to assign a value to a variable on its creation? Something like this:

```
var ProvisionHeaderCounter: Integer := 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. If you want to do this you will need to assign the value in the first line of your function.